# C# how to print asp:buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on a small program that gets data from mongoDB and matches it with other data. My program is currently printing out the data, but it needs to add a `<asp:button />`with an unique ID to it so I can save the data for each product.

Here is my code:

```
public void showCoolers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = "";
    var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    MongoServer server = mongoClient.GetServer(); 
    MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("mydb");
    MongoCollection<cpuCoolers> collection = database.GetCollection<cpuCoolers>("cpucoolers");
    foreach (cpuCoolers parts in collection.FindAll())
    {
        String _id = parts._id.ToString();
        items = items + "<tr><td>" + parts.Aanbieder + "</td><td> " + parts.Productnaam + "</td><td>" +  parts.Socket + "</td><td> " + parts.Geluidsterkte + "</td><td> " + parts.Prijs +"</td><td><asp:Button ID='x' runat='server' Text='Motherboard' CssClass='btn btn-block btn-primary'/></td></tr>";
    }
    lblProducts.Text = "<table><thead><tr><th>Provider</th><th>Productname</th><th>Socket</th><th>Sound production</th><th>Price</th><th>Add to MyPc!</th></thead>" + items + "</table>";
}
```

I print my data via changing the content of`lblProduct.Text` in my aspx file. If I add a asp:button to this it doesn't show up, however a regular Html button does, why is that and is there a way to print out a asp:button's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't render an asp.net button the way you are trying, you would need to use a regular html button as you found out.

The asp:button is something that asp.net interprets while it is building your page; by the time you _Click function is executed, its too late in the page lifecycle to render asp.net controls - so HTML buttons are your only option at that point in the page execution.

Here is an overview of the asp.net page life cycle that might help you understand it better:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx